# jquery DataTable add ID to TR element after row is dynamically added

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using this code to **init DataTable**:

```
    $('#table-groups').dataTable( {
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "bFilter": false,
    "bInfo": false,
    "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
    "aoColumns": [
     { "sClass": "name" },
     { "sClass": "tools", "bSortable": false},
     ],     
    });
```

Now I am adding rows via server-side script like this:

```
$('#table-groups').dataTable().fnAddData( ["<strong>"+$_returnvalue.name+"</strong>","<div class=\"cell edit\"> Group ID is: "+$_returnvalue.entryid+" </div>"]);
```

And my question: is there a way to insert value of `$_returnvalue.entryid` to be **ID** of the  `<tr>` ?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can use the [fnCreatedRow](http://www.datatables.net/usage/callbacks#fnCreatedRow) callback

You can do something like where `aData[0]` has to be the id.

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "fnCreatedRow": function( nRow, aData, iDataIndex ) {
        $(nRow).attr('id', aData[0]);
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wVUjR/)

Comment: You solution is THE BEST solution for dynamically created/filled DataTable. Thank you very much. P.S. maybe add "row" as prefix in attribute id

Answer (score 5):

```
 var MyUniqueID = "tr123"; // this is the uniqueId.
    var rowIndex = $('#MyDataTable').dataTable().fnAddData([ "column1Data", "column2Data"]);
    var row = $('#MyDataTable').dataTable().fnGetNodes(rowIndex);
    $(row).attr('id', MyUniqueID);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not using serverside datatable here. This answer may help those who are using serverside datatable and trying to put unique ID (from serverside, based on db data).

You just have to send the `ID` by this key: `DT_RowId` (from serverside, as response). It doesn't require any change in the frontend. More details of this can be found in the following link: https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/ids.html